# PCF Spring Boot webhdfs Kerebros Authentication: KDC has no support for encryption type (14) - BAD_ENCRYPTION_TYPE

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

We are trying to connect to webhdfs URL in a Microservice using the example given here 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSPT3X_3.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.admin.doc/doc/kerberos_httpfs.html

I have created the conf file for the same and kept in the resources location

```
    [libdefaults]
     allow_weak_crypto = true
     default_realm = CLOUD.CORP.XXXXXX.XXX
     # kdc will be obtained through DNS SRV
     dns_lookup_kdc = true
     dns_lookup_realm = true
     forwardable = true
     default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts
     default_etypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts
     default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts
     permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts
     ticket_lifetime = 24h
     rdns = true
    [realms]
    CLOUD.CORP.XXXXXX.XXX = {
     kdc = abc-dv-def0.cloud.corp.XXXXXX.XXX:88
     master_kdc = abc-dv-def0.cloud.corp.XXXXXX.XXX:88
    }
    [domain_realm]
     .cloud.corp.XXXXXX.XXX = CLOUD.CORP.XXXXXX.XXX
     cloud.corp.XXXXXX.XXX = CLOUD.CORP.XXXXXX.XXX
     abc-dv-def0.cloud.corp.XXXXXX.XXX = CLOUD.CORP.XXXXXX.XXX
```

The java code snippet is as follows

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
    conf.set("hadoop.home.dir", "/");
    UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
    System.out.println("--------------loginWithKeytab--------");
    UserGroupInformation loginUser = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(principal, keytabUrl);
    UserGroupInformation.setLoginUser(loginUser);

    String user = UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser().getUserName();
    System.out.println("Starting the connection for User:::"+user);

    try {
        System.out.println("Starting the connection::"+UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser());


        URL url = new URL("http://lb-abcdef-dv-abc.cloud.corp.xxxxxxx.xxx:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/xxx-xxxxx/xxxxx/data.txt?op=OPEN");
        HttpURLConnection connection = UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser()
                .doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<HttpURLConnection>() {
                    public HttpURLConnection run() throws Exception {
                        AuthenticatedURL.Token token = new AuthenticatedURL.Token();
                        return new AuthenticatedURL().openConnection(url,token);
                    }
                });
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        System.out.println("Connection Established:::"+connection.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println("Connection Established:::"+connection.getResponseMessage());
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        int ch;
        while((ch=in.read())!=-1)
        {
            System.out.println("File received...");
            System.out.println((char)ch);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have created my own buildpack for deployment to PCF and added the local_policy.jar for unlimited strenght (JCE) so that it gets overlay while unpacking in PCF. https://github.com/sivacham/java-buildpack

However I keep getting the same error

```
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.660+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Starting the connection for User:::xxx-xxxxx@CLOUD.CORP.XXXXXX.XXX : **After the Auth , I print the Current user Using UserGroupInformation**
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.660+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Starting the connection::xxx-xxxxx@CLOUD.CORP.XXXXXX.XXX (auth:KERBEROS) : **After the Auth , I print the Current user Using UserGroupInformation**

    2018-08-13T12:32:27.745+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Found ticket for xxx-xxxxx@CLOUD.CORP.XXXXXX.XXX to go to krbtgt/CLOUD.CORP.XXXXXX.XXX@CLOUD.CORP.XXXXXX.XXX expiring on Tue Aug 14 07:02:27 UTC 2018 : Ticket is created with 1 day expiry
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.746+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Entered Krb5Context.initSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.747+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Service ticket not found in the subject : **Does this mean that the Ticket is not passed to the URL ?**
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.747+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] >>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: same realm
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.747+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 18 17.
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.748+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] >>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.749+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] >>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.750+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] >>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=dhb2b-dv-kdsc0.cloud.corp.XXXXXX.XXX UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=735
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.750+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] >>> KDCXXXmunication: kdc=dhb2b-dv-kdsc0.cloud.corp.XXXXXX.XXX UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=735
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.770+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] >>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=231
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.770+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] >>> KdcAccessibility: remove dhb2b-dv-kdsc0.cloud.corp.XXXXXX.XXX:88
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.771+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] >>> KDCRep: init() encoding tag is 126 req type is 13
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.771+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] >>>KRBError:
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.771+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] cTime is Tue Jan 15 14:05:46 UTC 1985 474645946000
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.771+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sTime is Mon Aug 13 07:02:27 UTC 2018 1534143747000
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.771+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] suSec is 764299
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.771+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] error code is 14
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.771+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] error Message is KDC has no support for encryption type
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.771+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] cname is xxx-xxxxx@CLOUD.CORP.XXXXXX.XXX
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.771+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sname is HTTP/lb-abcdef-dv-abc.cloud.corp.XXXXXX.XXX@CLOUD.CORP.XXXXXX.XXX
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.771+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] msgType is 30
    2018-08-13T12:32:27.772+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] KrbException: KDC has no support for encryption type (14) - BAD_ENCRYPTION_TYPE
```

I have tried adding rc4-hmac as well but still get the same error.Any help is greatly appreciated .

Comment: I can't help with the kerberos issue, but you don't need to do this `I have created my own buildpack for deployment to PCF and added the local_policy.jar for unlimited strenght (JCE) so that it gets overlay while unpacking in PCF.`. The Java buildpack has shipped with unlimited strength JCE for quite some time now. Any recent 3.x and all 4.x versions will have it, no additional work necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found that the issue was in the keytab.
We were pointing the keytab to the node in the cluster  but the request was hitting the loadbalancer and it was failing there(as observed from KDC logs) . After adding the laodbalancer details in the keytab at thier end it worked fine and I was able to get a 201 created.